# Quantifiy image shift in pixels

Tags: matlab, image-processing, cross-correlation

I am using MATLAB to calculate cross-correlation between images. I have two 132*1024 images that are more or less the same, but one being shifted alongside the Y axis by somewhat like 50-70 pixels, and maybe a few pixels (<10) alongisde the X axis.

I used the `xcorr2` function to calculate the cross-correlation matrix, so I end up with a 263*2047 matrix, which I can easily 3D-plot using `mesh`. The surface plot looks perfectly fine but what I don't uderstand is : how do I find the "shift value" in pixels ? The max of the `xcorr2` matrix is at [130, 987] and I don't know how to relate this to the expected result that should be something like [50, 5].

Thanks a lot !

EDIT : I don't want to use the `imregister` method that has been proposed. My goal is to compare the `xcorr2` fuction with a cross-correlation code I made myself in C#.

Comment: This is very clearly explained in the documentation: https://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/xcorr2.html

Answer (score 0):

What you are dealing with here is a quite simple **rigid registration** problem.

Use the `imregister` method to register the two images (you can specify that only translation–movement in x/y–is allowed; rigid stands for translation+rotation).

https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imregister.html

Comment: Thanks for your advice, I will be looking into this right now !

Comment: I see that the `imregister` method is in fact a way to NOT have to perform crosscorrelation. This is not what I need, I want to compare the crosscorrelation `xcorr2`with another implementation I made with C#. What I want is to understand how to find the offset between the two images using the xcorr2 matrix.

Comment: Well if you insist in solving your registration problem through correlation, why don't you just search for the maximum in the correlation matrix as explained in the documentation?